# build substrate ink contract

Tags: rust-cargo, substrate, polkadot, parity-io, polkadot-js

I trying to create a substrate smart contract by following the tutorial as described in https://substrate.dev/substrate-contracts-workshop/#/0/setup. I have installed all the dependencies on Windows 10 OS. However, the process fails after completing 3 steps ( [3/5] Optimizing wasm file) with the following error message.

**"ERROR: Access is denied. (os error 5)"**

Please help me in resolving this error.

Thanks

Comment: I have used - "cargo +nightly contract build" command to build the contract

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try an admin console? But ideally developing in WSL2 is best if you can. You'll have a lot less trouble that way.